# Start reading large csv at specific row without iterating previous rows

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to read CSV file with 500 000 rows and 81 columns and insert it in database. CSV size is 160 MB

Following is my code

```
$file    = fopen($path, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
}
```

It works approximately 1 hour, access approximately 100 000 records and then stop processing and shows error "Connection was reset". I have tried increasing PHP execution time limit and memory limit but It is not a efficient solution.

Can I start reading CSV from specific row without iterating through previous rows?

Comment: Maybe you should create a batch program.

Comment: Will it work on linux server?

Comment: Something like [this](https://wpguru.co.uk/2014/02/how-to-run-php-from-the-command-line-in-linux)

Comment: I already edited lakh away from your previous question. Please use universal measurements instead of Indian words.

Comment: Since you are using a csv you could grab a slice of the csv by using a function similar to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22669242/revisions

I don't know if it will help you a lot though, it doesn't look that efficient. But it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The magical function you need is [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php). You can take a note where you ended last time and continue with processing. But you need to remember, that each line is of different length and therefore it is a bit difficult to find the correct position in the file.

I would recommend to get rid of the CSV in the first place. Use something like Sqlite with fixed row size.